# How can I write this format in twig 2020-12-11 11:06:02.748996+01

Tags: php, date, twig

how can I write this format

```
2020-12-11 11:06:02.748996+01
```

in my template twig

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you read the [twig date documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html)?

Comment: Yes 
But I can't figure out how to apply what's after the seconds (.748996)

Comment: Then you should have stated that in your question. Can you show the line of code where you output this date to show the format you're currently using?

Comment: ```
version.last_update |date("c", "Europe/Paris")
```

Comment: I find, thanks for your answers
I must use |date("Y-m-dTH:i:s.uZ+01")

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [`format` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), you'll see that `c` prints out a predefined ISO 8601 format. Since what you want is different, you'll need to devise a custom format. That will amount to the following:

```
'Y-m-d H:i:s.uO'
```

What these tokens represent (per documentation):

- `Y` - A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
- `m` - Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
- `d` - Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
- `H` - 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
- `i` - Minutes with leading zeros
- `s` - Seconds with leading zeros
- `u` - Microseconds
- `O` - Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) without colon between hours and minutes
- `:`, `-`, `.` and spaces are interpreted literally (as would any other characters that don't match a token)

Note that this will slightly differ from what you specified, in the way that it will have the minute value of the timezone included, so instead of:

```
2020-12-11 11:06:02.748996+01
```

you will have:

```
2020-12-11 11:06:02.748996+0100
```

If you really wish to remove the trailing zeros, you can achieve it by applying a [Twig `slice` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html) (but I would not recommend this, as some time zones are not a full hour apart and your data may be represented in an inaccurate manner in those cases).